# Making span inherit sibling width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `div` with a header element and a `span`.

How can I prevent the `span` from making the parent `div` larger?

i.e. only lets the `span`'s width be the width of the sibling heading.

Example:

```
<div class="media-body">
  <h4 class="media-heading">
    Lauren Ipsum
    <small>@ipsum - 2014-06-01T18:40:35.000Z</small>
  </h4>
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum..
  </span>
</div>
```

The `span` should not make the `div` and wider than if it wasn't there.

Example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAkue/)

Comment: No way just with CSS, I think. If you can use javascript/JQuery it's easy.

Comment: Not quite sure what is the question here. You have a problem with an inline element for streching out a block element... A block element stretch 100% (as long as there is no css behind it that prevents it).

Comment: @drip right, so is there a css that can prevent it? Besides a brute force width

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want the span element to remain to the size of its parent.

From looking at your code it appears you haven't specified the maximum width of the parent, so the span assumes that it is to keep flowing until it reaches the border of the container. Given that it's not set, the text keeps going until it hits the browser window.

Your options could be limited to 1) Setting a maximum width of the parent, and setting the `span` to `display: block;` or 2) setting a max width on the `span`.